# Cordova, não está responsive

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou aprendendo cordova aqui e estou com algumas dúvidas e problemas que citarei abaixo..

Dúvidas:
Como colocar tudo responsive com o Materialize?
Como implementar SQL depois?

Problemas:
Ele não está responsive, eu mudo de Iphone para Tablete e as coisas ficam fora de ordem.

Segue o código:

index.css

> main {
>       /* FOOTER */
>       flex: 1 0 auto; }
>
> body {
>       background-image: url("../img/bg.png");
>       /* FOOTER */
>       display: flex;
>       min-height: 100vh;
>       flex-direction: column; }
>
> ## logo {
>
> ```
> width: 30%;
> margin-top: 2em;
> margin-left: 8em; }
> ```
>
> ## logo2 {
>
> ```
> width: 20%;
> margin-left: 10em;
>  }
> ```
>
> ## account {
>
> ```
> margin-top: 2em;
> margin-left: 7em; }
> ```
>
> ## senha {
>
> ```
> margin-top: 1em;
> margin-left: 7em; }
> ```
>
> ## btnLogin {
>
> ```
> margin-top: -2em; }
> ```
>
> ## btnCadastrar {
>
> ```
> margin-top: 0.2em; }
> ```
>
> ## footer-text {
>
> ```
> margin-left: 9em; }
> ```
>
> ## footer {
>
> ```
> margin-top: 2.4em; }
> ```

index.html

> ```
>   <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <!-- LOGO -->
>     <img class="responsive-img" src="img/logo.png" id="logo">
>
>     <!-- LOGIN/SENHA -->
>     <div class="row">
>         <form class="col s12">
>     <div class="row">
>     <div id="account" class="input-field col s6">
>         <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
>         <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate">
>     <label for="icon_prefix">E-mail</label>
>     </div>
>     <div id="senha" class="input-field col s6">
>         <i class="material-icons prefix">https</i>
>         <input id="icon_https" type="password" class="validate">
>         <label for="icon_https">Senha</label>
>     </div>
>     </div>
> </form>   </div>
>
>      <!-- BOTÕES -->
>      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</a>
>      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btnCadastrar">CADASTRAR</a>
>
>      <!-- FOOTER -->
>     <footer id="footer" class="page-footer">
>       <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>           <div class="col l6 s12">
>           </div>
>           <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
>             <ul>
>               <li><a id="footer-text" class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Conheça o APP</a></li>
>             </ul>
>              <img class="responsive-img" src="img/logo2.png" id="logo2">
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="footer-copyright">
>         <div class="container">
>         MIND CODE © 2016 Direitos Autorais de Thiago Saad.
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </footer>
>
>
>   <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
> </body>   </html>
> ```

Comment: Acho que vc precisa de um framework css, ex: Bootstrap

Comment: @VitorNascimento estou utilizando o Materealize...